error TS2339: Property '_id' does not exist on type 'User'
below is my code for logout
export const logoutUser = async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    try {
        res.cookie("access_token", "", { maxAge: 1 });
        res.cookie("refresh_token", "", { maxAge: 1 });
        const userId = req.user?._id || '';
        console.log(userId)
        redis.del(userId);
        res.status(200).json({
            success: true,
            message: "Logged out successfully",
        });
    } catch (error: any) {
        return next(new ErrorHandler(error.message, 400));
    }
}

below is my code for Auth.ts
export const isAutheticated = async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  const access_token = req.cookies.access_token;
  if (!access_token) {
    return next(
      new ErrorHandler("Please login to access this resource", 400)
    );
  }
  const decoded = jwt.verify(access_token, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN as string) as JwtPayload;

  if (!decoded) {
    return next(new ErrorHandler("access token is not valid", 400));
  }

  const user = await redis.get(decoded.id);


  if (!user) {
    return next(
      new ErrorHandler("Please login to access this resource", 400)
    );
  }

  req.user = JSON.parse(user);
  next();

below is my code for index.d.ts
import { Request } from "express";
import { IUser } from "../models/user.model";

declare global {
    namespace Express {
        interface Request {
            user?: IUser
        }
    }
}

I have created the .d.ts file and also included it in tsconfig file. Still I'm not able to run this code I am getting error  Unable to compile TypeScript:
src/Controllers/user.controller.ts(169,34): error TS2339: Property '_id' does not exist on type 'User'.
